# Overriding getter in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, overriding, getter-setter

I have a situation where I need to override the getter of a property.

Let's say we have:

```
public class MyBaseClass {
    private var _name: String
    public internal(set) var name: String {
        get {
            return self._name
        }
        set {
            self._name = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing really fancy, I guess.

Now, if I try to override the getter in a derived class:

```
public class MyDerivedClass: MyBaseClass {
    public var name: String {
        get {
            return "Derived - \(super.name)"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the compile error: *Cannot override mutable property with read-only property 'name'*.

If I try to add the setter and overriding it:

```
public class MyDerivedClass: MyBaseClass {
    public internal(set) var name: String {
        get {
            return "Derived - \(super.name)"
        }
        set {
            super.name = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error: *Setter of overriding var must be as accessible as the declaration it overrides*.

And if I try the following:

```
public class MyDerivedClass: MyBaseClass {
    public internal(set) var name: String {
        get {
            return "Derived - \(super.name)"
        }
    }
}
```

Then, the compiler crashes...

How can I achieve to override only the getter ?

Comment: just to clarify, you want a computed variable (name) that can only be set internally but the value of which is essentially read-only outside of these dimensions:

"Internal access enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that module. You typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a framework’s internal structure."

While _name is private and setting and getting is confined to source file.

Comment: I've had it confirmed on twitter by one of the Swift compiler engineers that this behaviour looks like a bug.

Comment: Exactly, I'm currently trying to create a framework, and I got the case where the setter of the base class had to be internal (so that only other classes of this framework could use it). 
I tried also to have `name` directly as a stored property, but then I couldn't override the getter (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public class MyBaseClass {
    private var _name: String = "Hi"
    public internal(set) var name: String {
        get {
            return self._name
        }
        set {
            self._name = newValue
        }
    }
}

public class MyDerivedClass:MyBaseClass {
    override public var name: String {
        get {
            return "Derived - \(super.name)"
        }
        set {
            super._name = newValue
        }
    }
}

MyDerivedClass().name
```

**EDIT**

This code works for me in a playground, placing it in the Sources -> SupportCode.swift file

```
public class MyBaseClass {
private var _name: String = "Hi"
public internal(set) var name: String {
    get {
        return self._name
    }
    set {
        self._name = newValue
    }
}
public init() {

}

}

public class MyDerivedClass:MyBaseClass {
    override public var name: String {
        get {
            return "Derived - \(super.name)"
        }
        set {
           // do nothing
        }
    }
   public override init() {

    }
}
```

It's a bit of a bodge because I get the same warning as you that `internal(set)` cannot be placed before the overridden subclass variable. It may well be a bug.  And also I'm cheating to make sure the setter of the derived class does nothing.

A more common use of `internal(set)` or `private(set)` is to have code like this, which is similar to that in the documentation:

```
public class MyBaseClass {
    public private(set) var _name: String = "Hi"
    public var name: String {
        get {
            return self._name
        }
        set {
            self._name = newValue
        }
    }
    public init() {

    }

}

public class MyDerivedClass:MyBaseClass {
    override public var name: String {
        get {
            return "Derived - \(super.name)"
        }
        set {
           super._name = newValue
        }
    }
   public override init() {

    }
}
```

Here the setter can be read directly with `MyDerivedClass()._name` but it cannot be altered, e.g. this `MyDerivedClass()._name = "Fred"` would raise an error but `MyDerivedClass().name = "Fred"` would be OK.

Comment: Will that expose the setter publicly ?

Answer (score 7):

### Problem 1

MyBaseClass **does not compile** because:

1. it has a stored property (_name)
2. this stored property is non optional so it cannot be nil
3. there is no initializer to populate it

So first of all we need to add a proper initializer to MyBaseClass

```
public class MyBaseClass {
    private var _name: String
    public internal(set) var name: String {
        get { return self._name }
        set { self._name = newValue }
    }
    init(name : String){
        _name = name
    }
}
```

### Problem 2

Now we can declare `MyDerivedClass` that overrides the computed property:

1. we need to use the magic keyword **override**
2. we need to provide both the setter and the getter

Here's the code:

```
public class MyDerivedClass: MyBaseClass {
    public override var name: String {
        get { return "Derived - \(super.name)" }
        set { super.name = newValue }
    }
}
```

### Test

From my playground:

```
let somethingWithAName = MyDerivedClass(name: "default name")
println(somethingWithAName.name) // > "Derived - default name"
somethingWithAName.name = "another name"
println(somethingWithAName.name) // > "Derived - another name"
```

Comment: Placing internal(set) before the computed variable indicates that this can be retrieved publicly but only set internally. I think BPCorp wants to replicate these conditions in subclass within the overridden property but it doesn't appear possible because you can't repeat use of internal(set). A bug? An unexpected pattern of use?